# What brand is this BMX frame?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image][image]

Can anyone tell me what bmx frame this is? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Reminds me of Cult logos but I doubt it's that. You're probably better of asking this on a proper bmx forum.

Comment: Are there any other decals or logos anywhere on the bike to go on?   This logo looks vaguely like two letters, tilt your head left and its EI, but tilt right and its H over W.

Comment: If you ask me, the top image looks like '13'. This tails in with the Halfords-supported 13 Intrinsic Beta road bike from back in 2015. Perhaps the same company.

Oh yeah, #PostNecromancy for the win! :P

Comment: it might be easier to identify if you show the whole BMX frame - frame styles are partly how you identify a BMX - my FTB has no decals but it's shape let's those who know that it's an FTB :~)